# How to publish Orchard List as custom XML or JSON

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Ideally I'd like to be able to expose a List of custom content types via an RSS feed.  However I'd be satisfied if i could just get all the items in the list and publish that as custom XML or JSON.  Can anyone provide a code snippet that would be used to get all the items for a given list id?

Comment: I don't know too much but have a look at this article, will help you understand how to generate the xml/json, you'll only have to figure out how to read a List of Content Items. http://www.rudigrobler.net/blog/creating-a-sitemap-module-for-orchard

Comment: I think that is my real problem.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the contents of a list in code in orchard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer I gave on the Orchard forums:

It's not there by default, which I think is something we should fix in 1.1 (I filed http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/17399 to keep track of it, feel free to vote it up).

It can be added by a module though. You could build that into a handler that would get a reference to a IFeedManager and Register a new feed for list content items. You can look at the blog module for an example of adding a feed. There is also some information in that blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/04/07/rss-feeds-in-orchard.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much this was a big help.  from looking at the code in the blogs i discovered that all i had to do was navigate to the link /rss?containerid=<listid> and i'd get an rss feed of the items in my list.